# Connect to SignalR Hubs using Ocelot API Gateway

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, blazor-client-side, asp.net-core-signalr, ocelot

I am trying to connect Blazor client to SignalR hub in a simple microservice through the Ocelot API gateway. I am using SSL for all the ASP.NET Core projects.

The gateway works fine when calling https endpoints and I get "Connection Id Required" when I call the signalR hub endpoint directly from the gateway browser (which shows Ocelot routes correctly).

Unfortunately, I get the following error when I try to connect to the hub from the blazor client application

> fail: Ocelot.Errors.Middleware.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
> requestId: 0HM4U0GLR9ACR:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Exception caught in global error handler, exception message: Only Uris starting with 'ws://' or 'wss://' are supported. (Parameter 'uri'), exception stack:    at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Ocelot.WebSockets.Middleware.WebSocketsProxyMiddleware.Proxy(HttpContext context, String serverEndpoint)
> at Ocelot.WebSockets.Middleware.WebSocketsProxyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis.AnalysisMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Ocelot.DownstreamUrlCreator.Middleware.DownstreamUrlCreatorMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis.AnalysisMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Ocelot.LoadBalancer.Middleware.LoadBalancingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis.AnalysisMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Ocelot.Request.Middleware.DownstreamRequestInitialiserMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis.AnalysisMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Ocelot.Multiplexer.MultiplexingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis.AnalysisMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Ocelot.DownstreamRouteFinder.Middleware.DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis.AnalysisMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis.AnalysisMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)

The following are my code.

Ocelot API Startup file

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
                //policy.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials();
            });
        });
        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.UseOcelot().Wait();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

ocelot.json Configuration

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/currency/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7004
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api-currency/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/currency/{everything}",
      "ReRouteIsCaseSensitive": false,
      "DownstreamScheme": "wss",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7004
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api-currencyhub/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS" ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:7000",
    "RequestIdKey": "OcRequestId"

  }
}
```

Microservice API Startup file

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
                //policy.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials();
                //policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials();
            });
        });
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<CurrencyHub>("/api/currency/maincurrencyhub");
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Blazor client Razor Page

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<h1>Welcome to SignalR with Blazor</h1>
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="async () => await ConnectToServer()" disabled="@isConnected">Connect</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="async () => await OnGateway()">Gateway</button>
<h3>Connection Status: @connectionStatus</h3>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        @foreach (var item in notifications)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <h4>@item</h4>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    //string gatewayUrl = "wss://localhost:7000/api-currency/maincurrencyhub";
    string gatewayUrl = "https://localhost:7000/api-currency/maincurrencyhub";
    HubConnection gatewayConnection = null;

    bool isConnected = false;
    string connectionStatus = "Closed";

    List<string> notifications = new List<string>();

    private async Task ConnectToServer()
    {
        gatewayConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            //.WithUrl(gatewayUrl)

            .WithUrl(gatewayUrl, opt => { opt.SkipNegotiation = true; opt.Transports = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.WebSockets; })
            .Build();

        try
        {
            await gatewayConnection.StartAsync();

            connectionStatus = "Connected :-)";

            gatewayConnection.Closed += async (s) =>
            {
                isConnected = false;
                connectionStatus = "Disconnected";
                await gatewayConnection.StartAsync();
                isConnected = true;
            };
            gatewayConnection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", m =>
            {
                notifications.Add(m);
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    async Task OnGateway()
    {
        await gatewayConnection.InvokeAsync("Send", "Na Gode");
    }

}
```

I have tried to follow [Ocelot not passing websockets to microservice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63472028/7467969) without avail.
Can some one guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi, were you able to make it work? I'm facing the same issue...

Comment: Did you resolve it? I m thinking to use nginx ... =/

Answer (score 5):

This is the Ocelot configuration that finally allowed me to setup client => Ocelot => signalR server communications.

```js
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/hub/",
      "DownstreamScheme": "ws",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/hub/",
      "QoSOptions": {
        "TimeoutValue": 320000
      },
      "Priority": 50
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/hub/{path}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "ws",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/hub/{path}",
      "QoSOptions": {
        "TimeoutValue": 320000
      },
      "Priority": 50
    },
```

The signalR server is configured to listen to /hub.

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("hub");
    });
```

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Does `QoSOptions` really have some effect?

Comment: I'm not sure. I can't remember if I verified if it had an effect or not.

Comment: What does ws stand for? Why do we need it?

Comment: I'm guessing 'ws' is short for websocket.

I needed it in my configuration to get it to work. You might not need it if for example you are only using long polling over SignalR. That's just an educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

In ocelot.json, try to remove the second route and leave just the first one but using "wss" as DownstreamScheme, like this:

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/currency/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "wss",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7004
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/currency/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS" ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:7000",
    "RequestIdKey": "OcRequestId"

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem between Ocelot and SignalR Hub with NGinx Finally,

My Develepment configuration of Nginx is

```
server {
  listen 2000; #Entry point and redirect to ocelot to 2005 to start site

  #Ocelot configuration in root
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost.com:2005; 
  }

  #SignalR hub (devicehub)
  location /devicehub {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2004;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

NOTA: Sorry, I've lost the references for hub configuration (/devicehub) but I can update later.

More detail solution (You can skip if you know about docker/ocelot)

This is the docker-compose file to start nginx

```
version: '3.4'

services:
# ... 
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
        #For windows development doesn't work without c:, but in linux you can change to / with other yaml file
      - c:/data/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 2000:2000
```

To start nginx

`docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml"  up -d`

or

`docker-compose up -d`

Best regards